# Hide "Or drop files" for file lightning-input

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, slds

I have a lightning-input with type file so I can upload files.  I don't want the little box that says "Or drop files" that shows up beside the upload button to show.  Is there a way to hide it?
[image: upload screenshot]

I've already seen the solution at [Lightning:input type="file" change the "Upload Files" text](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/200979/lightninginput-type-file-change-the-upload-files-text), but it isn't working for me in LWC.

.html

```
<lightning-input
     type="file"
     onchange={handleFileUpload}
     accept="*"
     multiple></lightning-input>
```

.css

```
.THIS .slds-file-selector__dropzone .slds-file-selector__text{
    display: none !important;
}

.THIS .slds-file-selector__text .slds-medium-show {
    display: none !important;
}
```

rendered .html

```
<span lightning-input_input="" class="slds-file-selector__text slds-medium-show">Or drop files</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can access this because of the [shadow dom limiting your access to it](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246887/target-inner-elements-of-standard-lightning-web-components-with-css). may have to build one from scratch : /

Comment: I was afraid of that, thanks

Comment: I would recommend using one of the workarounds from that thread, such as `loadStyle` or `<style>`. They're kind of hacky but you're going to have a really hard time recreating the standard upload component

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is one workaround that I used in my case

The idea is to 'hide' DropZone text.
For that you need to create your css class and add your class to the lightning-file-upload component

```
<lightning-file-upload
        class="slds-align_absolute-center removeDropZone"
        name="fileUploader"
        accept={acceptedFormats}
        onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}>
</lightning-file-upload>
```

Then let's go to the css file and add that lines

```
 .removeDropZone {
      color: #ffffff;
      --lwc-borderWidthThin: 0px;
 }
```

The result:
[image: The result]

Note: It does not help you too remove drop zone, this way helps to **hide** it.