# Update CSS Of Lighting input of Type File (LWC)

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

I want to update CSS of `<lightning-input type="file"` 
I want to change the Text of button as well as want to move attach button next to upload file.
I want to remove text `or drop files` 
I tried with following but its not working:

```
    .slds-file-selector__text{
        display: none ;
    }
    
    
    .slds-file-selector__button {
        font-size: 0 ;
    }
    
   .slds-file-selector__button :after{
        content: 'Select File' ;
        font-size: .8125rem ;
        color: rgba(27, 82, 151, 1.0) ;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71556078/remove-or-drop-files-section-part-from-file-upload-button-in-lightning-web-com

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/320523/hide-or-drop-files-for-file-lightning-input